# File not found: archive/constants.pkl at Python Pytorch

Tags: python, serialization, pytorch, torchvision

I'm getting error while preparing List of operators of your serialized torchscript model. What is the issue here? Is it coming when loading it?

***Python code***

```
# Dump list of operators used by MobileNetV2:
import torch, yaml

root = '/content/drive/My Drive/Monitoring/'
model = torch.jit.load(root+'model.pt')
ops = torch.jit.export_opnames(model)
with open('MobileNetV2.yaml', 'w') as output:
    yaml.dump(ops, output)
```

***Stack Trace***

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-8b61c35fb898> in <module>()
      3 
      4 root = '/content/drive/My Drive/Monitoring/'
----> 5 model = torch.jit.load(root+'model.pt')
      6 ops = torch.jit.export_opnames(model)
      7 with open('MobileNetV2.yaml', 'w') as output:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/jit/_serialization.py in load(f, map_location, _extra_files)
    159     cu = torch._C.CompilationUnit()
    160     if isinstance(f, str) or isinstance(f, pathlib.Path):
--> 161         cpp_module = torch._C.import_ir_module(cu, f, map_location, _extra_files)
    162     else:
    163         cpp_module = torch._C.import_ir_module_from_buffer(

RuntimeError: [enforce fail at inline_container.cc:222] . file not found: archive/constants.pkl
```

Comment: How did you save `model.pt`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to load model directly without `jit`:
`torch.load(model_path, map_location=device)`

If you want to load model via `torch.jit.load`, you have to save your model via `torch.jit.trace`, for example:

```
model = ...
model.eval()
input_tensor = torch.rand(1, 3, 224, 224)
script_model = torch.jit.trace(model, input_tensor)
script_model.save("model.jit.pt")
```

You may would like to check [this thread](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/pytorchstreamreader-failed-locating-file-constants-pkl-file-not-found/169884).